# CocoaPods with mixed subdependencies

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I'm testing a pod I'm working on which uses Swift (.framework) and has a static dependency:

`s.dependency 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.2.1'`

This way, I must use `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile of my testing project, but I'm getting the following error:

`The 'Pods-X' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: ...`

Unfortunately it's <s>impossible</s> a bit complicated to require a dynamic version of the lib from Google as [suggested by a CP team member](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5483#issuecomment-224570565) :/

Which would be the best approach in this case?

Thanks